What is this episode of Monk I'm remembering?
A few years ago, I watched an episode of Monk from someone's box set.
All I remember about the episode is that Adrian befriends a young boy (I think), and this makes him temporarily forget about his obsessive-compulsive disorder. I remember he plays with the child on some grass and doesn't mind touching the ground or getting dirty.
What baffles me is that recently I watched every episode of monk (all 125 episodes) - or at least I think I did - but I can't remember this being in any of the episodes.
I do know that the episode in question is not Mr. Monk Goes Camping.

A similar scene happens in Mr. Monk and the Kid (Season 3, Episode 16).

A severed finger turns up in the park, and Monk's only source of information is the two-year-old boy who found the finger.

Near the end, he plays with the boy (Tommy) and rolls around in the grass. You can see some frames from the scene here, around 0:40:



